# Persistent ignored file with SVN

Tags: svn

Is it possible to keep a file that is not part of the repository into the working copy? I mean, the file would be an ignored file, but also will not be eliminated by removing unversioned items.

Thank you very much.

EDIT: With TortoiseSVN, if you hold shift key and then right click a folder on explorer, an extended menu shows. This extended menu has a command to remove unversioned items.

Comment: How do you remove unversioned items?  (I don't mean in the general case but specifically how you do it).

Comment: It seems you refer this this: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-rename.html#tsvn-dug-rename-del-unversioned. I have never used that command. Why would you used it? `svn:ignore` just tells svn to disregard that file, so it won't suggest it for adding etc.

Comment: Delete unversioned items is useful if, for example, in the same working copy you work with two different compilers or IDEs. In my case VS6 and VS2008.

Comment: If you do so, just have them write their intermediate and output files to different folders. In a project I used to work in that was done by having all compilers etc. write to `_bin/<tool-name>/<version>`. For you, `_bin\vc6` and `_bin\vc9` seems good enough. VC6 I'm not sure about anymore, because it's too long ago, but in VC9 you can set, e.g., `$(SolutionDir)\vc9\$(ConfigurationName)\obj` and `$(SolutionDir)\vc9\$(ConfigurationName)\bin`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as SVN is concerned an ignored file is an ignored file so if you want to manage some of these files differently you'll need to script it yourself.

I don't know if the 'Delete Unversioned Items' command removes files that are not under version control or in not an `svn:ignore` list, but if it doesn't you could not ignore the files that you want to persist.  If I remember correctly (I don't use Windows anymore), you can get TortoiseSVN to ignore unversioned items when you use the interface to check modifications etc.

Comment: Yes, the delete unversioned items command removes files with svn:ignore property. I said persistent ignored file cause I do not want svn to add the file in a check-in (ignored) and I do not want "Delete unversioned Items" command to delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

This is really old. What the user wanted was a file which was ignored by SVN, but still exists.

the way to do so is, while at the working directory

`svn propedit svn:ignore .`

and there place the name of the file, or, for example *.cfg